# Pandas Group By: Not able to retain the original dataframe post groupby

Tags: python, pandas

This problem may be trivial one. I have a dataframe `df` as follows

```
DealerID    ZMONTH    ZREGION    Cust_Cat     ZBAS_QTY   ZBAS_VAL
1001        201905    ABC        M            200        750
1001        201906    ABC        N            300        480
1001        201907    NOP        P            800        1156
1002        201905    PQR        M            350        525
1002        201906    PST        M            480        690
1002        201907    SNP        P            200        780
```

I want to apply `df.groupby()` so that for each `DealerID` I get the row that has `max()` ZBAS_VAL. In other words, the resultant dataframe should look like

```
DealerID    ZMONTH    ZREGION    Cust_Cat     ZBAS_QTY   ZBAS_VAL
1001        201907    NOP        P            800        1156
1002        201907    SNP        P            200        780
```

My Approach so far:

```
df = df.groupby(['DealerID'])['ZBAS_VAL'].max().reset_index()
```

However, such approach is returning only `ZBAS_VAL` and `DealerID` columns. What I want is all other remaining column.

Any clue?

Comment: Use `df = df.loc[df.groupby(['DealerID'])['ZBAS_VAL'].idxmax()]`

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering what if instead of `max` we need to `sum` the column `ZPUR_RECE`

Comment: Plus I am getting `AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'idmax'`

Comment: then pleae use some another aswer with sort_values and drop_duplicates

Comment: @jezrael: After `groupby` I am getting some unexpected `NaN` values. These are not supposed to be present. Any clue? Besides, instead `idmax()` I am using `max`

Comment: not understand why use `max` instead `idxmax`, reason of NaNs is used `max` here

Comment: Ok. Got it rectified.